# Adding a leaf to Binary Search Tree, Haskell

Tags: haskell, binary-tree

The type is defined as

```
data BST = MakeNode BST String BST
          | Empty
```

I'm trying to add a new leaf to the tree, but I don't really understand how to do it with recursion.

the function is set up like this

```
add :: String -> BST -> BST
```

Comment: Your definition of `BST` won't work. I think you mean `data BST = MakeNode String BST BST | Empty`, right?

Comment: yeah, that was a typo. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The advantage of using binary trees is that you only need to look at the "current part" of the tree to know where to insert the node.

So, let's define the `add` function:

```
add :: String -> BST -> BST
```

If you insert something into an empty tree (Case #1), you just create a leaf directly:

```
add s Empty = MakeNode Empty s Empty
```

If you want to insert something into a node (Case #2), you have to decide which sub-node to insert the value in. You use comparisons to do this test:

```
add s t@(MakeNode l p r) -- left, pivot, right
  | s > p     = Node l p (add s r) -- Insert into right subtree
  | s < p     = Node (add s l) p r -- Insert into left subtree
  | otherwise = t -- The tree already contains the value, so just return it
```

Note that this will not rebalance the binary tree. Binary tree rebalancing algorithms can be very complicated and will require a lot of code. So, if you insert a sorted list into the binary tree (e.g. `["a", "b", "c", "d"]`), it will become very unbalanced, but such cases are very uncommon in practice.

Comment: @dflemstr could you explain the @ symbol quickly?

Comment: The `@` symbol creates a name for the whole pattern to the right of it. So, if I do `t @ (MakeNode l p r)`, it's like saying `let t = MakeNode l p r in` in the code that follows, except that the program won't create a new `MakeNode`; it will just reuse the old one.

Comment: okay, so its makes it so you can either use the the whole BST by using t, and use the pattern by using (MakeNode l p r), basically?

Comment: Yes, you could describe it like that.

Comment: okay, thanks alot. I was trying to do something like that yesterday I a didn't know how.