# how to access number value of tree node with Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm going through a Haskell tutorial https://www.futurelearn.com/courses/functional-programming-haskell/9/steps/1103477 and this section is calling for a function that inserts a node to a binary tree.  I'd like to add the constraint that the tree is a BST and as such would like to define my base case as something like "if the value to insert is less than the value at the leaf node, add a left node, else add a right node".  There's a similar post here [Adding a leaf to Binary Search Tree, Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9622044/adding-a-leaf-to-binary-search-tree-haskell) but it appears to apply a technique that's yet to be introduced using the @.  If trying to implement this, I'm struggling to find a way to access the number value of the leaf node. Also, I'm unsure as to which node I'd return.  I'm tempted to return the point of insertion.  Any help would be much appreciated.

The typedef of the method is as follows

```
data Tree = Leaf | Node Int Tree Tree deriving Show

insertNodeToBST :: Tree -> Int -> Tree
insertNodeToBST Leaf value =
  if value < LeafValue
    then (Node value (Node value null null) null)
  else (Node value null (Node value null null))
```

Comment: when you see `t@(...)` in a pattern just replace every instance you see of `t` with `(...)` on the right side and you should be good to go. You should be perfectly able to apply this to the question you found there.

Comment: In that data type leaves have no value, unless you call a "leaf" something like `Node v Leaf Leaf`, i.e. the node just over two `Leaf`.

Answer (score 0):

`Leaf`s have no value, so you cannot extract a value from them<sup>*</sup>. For `Node`s, you can use pattern matching, as usual:

```
insertNodeToBST (Node valueInTree leftChild rightChild) value = ...
```

<sup>*</sup> This doesn't mean you're stuck if you see a `Leaf`. There is a canonical best answer for the right hand side of `insertNodeToBST Leaf value = ...` -- think about it!